# Can't remove element from jsTree in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have a customized jsTree in a `html` page.
When the user clicks a `.delete` icon in the jsTree, I redirect the user to the same page, with a query string of "delete", and then I execute the logic to remove that user from that listing (maybe some ajax here would be more user friendly, but I didn't actually code the page).

This works without a hitch on Firefox and Chrome, but on IE I'm experiencing some trouble. Weird trouble.

First of them: if the Developer Tools of IE is open, the thing works. If it isn't, it doesn't work. HTTP inspection revealed that jsTree is not getting the HTML from the defined `url` parameter, so, it is begin updated by the server, but jsTree is not getting the updated HTML back.
Interesting enough, if the Developer Tools is open, the request is sent off, and everything works.

Here's the code for the jsTree part:

```
  $('#jstree_demo').jstree({
            "core": {
                "animation": 0,
                "check_callback": true,
                "themes": { "stripes": true },
                'data': {
                    'url': function (node)
                    {
                        var ret = '/Some/Ajax/Page/Request.ashx?action=' + initialType;

                        if (node.data != null && node.data.nextType != null)
                            ret = '/Some/Ajax/Page/Request.ashx?action=' + node.data.nextType;

                        if (node.id === '#') {
                            ret += '&UserID=<%=Session("UserID")%>';
                        }

                        return ret;
                    }
                }
            },
            "plugins": [
              "search","state", "types", "wholerow"
            ]
        }).on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
            // some event handler
        });                           

    });
```

The code for deleting is pretty straightforward: a couple `update` statements. That is actually working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a caching issue. Since `core.data` in jsTree is a standard jQuery AJAX config try adding this:

```
'data': {
    'cache' : false,
    'url': function (node) ...
```

That will make jQuery append a timestamp to your GET request, which will bust the cache and you will always hit the server.

Comment: yes, this is probably what's happening... I'll update it and if this is it, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Yes, it was precisely this. Thank you!